# libGDX project not building after adding firebase (Android Studio)

Tags: android, firebase, libgdx

i just finished my project and it worked fine but when I  decided to integrate Firebase through android studios firebase assistant to it the project doesn't sync and I get these errors and I can't seem to figure out what to do i have listed all my gradle files down below . i have tried every possible answer on the web but nothing seems to work thanks in advance

```
 **ERROR'S**
 Error:(23, 34) error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
 Error:(24, 34) error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
 Error:(25, 34) error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
 Error:(26, 34) error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
Error:(27, 34) error: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
Error:(56, 15) error: cannot find symbol class AdView
Error:(58, 5) error: cannot find symbol class AdView
Error:(59, 13) error: cannot find symbol class InterstitialAd
Error:(343, 13) error: cannot find symbol class AdView
Error:(373, 35) error: cannot find symbol class AdView
 Error:(129, 30) error: cannot find symbol class InterstitialAd
 Error:(131, 42) error: cannot find symbol class AdListener
Error:(344, 22) error: cannot find symbol class AdView
Error:(345, 26) error: cannot find symbol variable AdSize
Error:(374, 9) error: cannot find symbol class AdRequest
Error:(374, 44) error: package AdRequest does not exist
Error:(425, 29) error: cannot find symbol class AdRequest
Error:(425, 74) error: package AdRequest does not exist
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

android gradle

```
android {
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
compileSdkVersion 23
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 25
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4G"

}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
}
}/*
// needed to add JNI shared libraries to APK when compiling on CLI
 tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'libs'))
}*/
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
    def outputDir = null
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
    if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
    if (outputDir != null) {
        copy {
            from zipTree(jar)
            into outputDir
            include "*.so"
        }
    }
}
}
afterEvaluate {
tasks.matching {
    it.name.startsWith('dex')
}.each { dx ->
    if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
        dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
    } else {
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    }
}
}

task run(type: Exec) {
def path
def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
if (localProperties.exists()) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
        properties.load(instr)
    }
    def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
    if (sdkDir) {
        path = sdkDir
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }
} else {
    path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
}

def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.buzz.dodge/AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
// need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
// ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
    }
}


classpath {
    plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
    containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
}

project {
    name = appName + "-android"
    natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
    buildCommands.clear();
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
    buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
    buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
}
 }
 // sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
 idea {
module {
    sourceDirs += file("src");
    scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

    iml {
        withXml {
            def node = it.asNode()
            def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
            builder.current = node;
            builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                    configuration {
                        option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
 dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

BaseGameUtils build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

  }
 }

 dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.0.1"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1"
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
afterEvaluate {
tasks.matching {
    it.name.startsWith('dex')
}.each { dx ->
    if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
        dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
    } else {
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    }
}
}

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4G"
}
}
```

dodge build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}

allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"

version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = 'Smove'
    gdxVersion = '1.5.6'
    roboVMVersion = '1.0.0'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.3'
    ashleyVersion = '1.3.1'
    aiVersion = '1.5.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
}
 }

 project(":desktop") {
apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

 }
  }

 project(":core")     {
 apply plugin: "java"


dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
}
 }

project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

 dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    compile project(":BaseGameUtils")
    compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
}
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136826/discussion-on-question-by-l-kohli-libgdx-project-not-building-after-adding-fireb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Version: 7.8.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required

That error is straightforward, you need a minimum of `9.0.0`

See the [latest versions here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split)

> Error:(32, 39) error: package `com.google.android.gms.appstate` does not exist
>      Error:(293, 28) error: cannot find symbol variable `AppStateManager`
>      Error:(294, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable `AppStateManager`

There is [`AppState`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/appstate/AppState), but no AppState**Manager**

And if you compile this

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.0.1"
```

That package does, in fact, exist.

[`com.google.android.gms.appstate`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/appstate/package-summary)

However, if you open that link, `AppStateManager` does not exist at all there. So, I think you have copied and used some code that either old or `AppStateManager` is a class you have failed to include from somewhere else.

---

Similarly, this package exists when you

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1"
```

[`com.google.android.gms.ads`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/ads/package-summary)

---

If we see on the [Google games Github samples](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AppState), this comment confirms my answer.

> Appstate API is gone after 7.8

Comment: i just removed import com.google.android.gms.appstate.AppStateManager; but now i have got tone more errors l

Comment: Well, I don't think you can include Firebase the way you are asking because it requires a version of GooglePlayServices that doesn't include the classes you are using. You could instead setup a web server using Firebase Javascript API. And perform REST requests against that.

Comment: i just wish to use the analytics feature of firebase and nothing else please help me out

Comment: You code should work as soon as you re-write it using the latest API. Otherwise, you are stuck using the old Google Analytics API rather than new Firebase Analytics

Comment: okay so i rewrote the whole code and now it works like a charm thank you for your consistent guidance and support even after few of my stupid mistakes  :)

Comment: @l.kohli Feel free to add your own answer for an overview of what you needed to change to get the code working.

Answer (score 0):

add `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'` as dependency in your android build.gradle file.

Comment: hey sorry to disturb you again but i just Declared the FirebaseAnalytics object at the top of my activity and Then initialize it in the onCreate() method and compiled it but now i am getting these errors Error:(85, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable FirebaseAnalytics Error:(63, 13) error: cannot find symbol class FirebaseAnalytics

Comment: FirebaseAnalytics is in com.google.firebase:firebase-core library and you already added it

Comment: How you initialize FirebaseAnalytics object ?

Comment: @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

Comment: check have you imported  import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

Answer (score 0):

I  am having same issues, BasicGamesUtil is compiled against '8.4.0' if you try to add Fire base I get same errors. Regrettably I am unable to add Fire base at all and will be using the older Play Service Analytics. Base Game Utils will not compile against a newer Play Services, have tried all sorts of ways to get it to compile, when I do, I get missing item like yourself.